# Spark Scala: write some sequence files into one folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a task to write some sequence files, for example: sequence1, sequence2, sequence3 into one folder.
If I'm trying like that

```
  sequence1.saveAsSequenceFile("home/sample1")
  sequence2.saveAsSequenceFile("home/sample1")
  sequence3.saveAsSequenceFile("home/sample1")
```

I receive the error on second line: "directory home/sample1 already exists.

Anybody know, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can't you combine them into a single rdd and then save them?

Comment: I forgote to notice, I have some restrictions on data size, which might be handled by spark-job. So I can't glue all my rdd into one single rdd, because the total size of this rdd will exceed limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Just union them

```
val rddUnion = sequence1.union(sequence2).union(sequence3)
```

And then write them all together

```
rddUnion.saveAsSequenceFile("home/sample1")
```

Comment: I forgote to notice, I have some restrictions on data size, which might be handled by spark-job. So I can't glue all my files into one single file, because the total size of this file will exceed limitations.